# Why array.push can not trigger the re-rendering UI, but array.concat can?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I want to re-render my UI base on the value of array a as follows:

```
const [a, setA] = useState([<sample_data>];
...
function update(newValue) {
   // use push method to append the new element into a
   a.push(newValue);
   setA(a);

   // use concat to create new array that includes a & new element
   setA([].concat(a,[newValue]);
}
```

If I use push, the re-render doesn't trigger, but using concat can.
It's weird to me, the array a really changes in both of cases, why only the concat trigger the re-rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setA checks using `oldValue === newValue`

```
function setA(newValue) {
   const same = oldValue === newValue;
   if (!same) {
      update(...);
   }
}
```

In the push case you're passing the same array

```
a.push(..)
setA(a);
same = a === a  // true
```

Concat creates a new array which you pass in

```
setA(a.concat(...))
same = a === newArray  // false
```

note you can use the spread operator

```
setA([...a, newValue]);
```

It's apparently [much faster than concat](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-spread)

Answer (score 0):

Both work differently.

**concat()**

`Array.prototype.concat()` returns a new array with concatenated element without even touching in original array. It's a shallow copy.

**push()**

`Array.prototype.push()` adds an element into original array and returns an integer which is its new array length.

If you are using ES6, you can use the spread operator

```
const [a, setA] = useState([<sample_data>];
...
function update(newValue) {
   setA([].concat(a,[newValue]);

   or

   setA([...a, newValue])
}
```

Comment: @doannx if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.